# RSpec/Capybara can't find link to image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I want to use RSpec and Capybara to simulate clicking on an image, but I cannot do it.

My error is this:

```
Failure/Error: click_on "icon_red_heart.png"

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible css "#image-button"
```

spec/features/posts_spec.rb

```
scenario "push an image" do  
  visit posts_path
  expect(page).to have_current_path(posts_path)
  find('#image-button').click
end
```

likes/_likes.html.erb

```
   <%= button_to post_like_path(post, like), id: "image-button",method: :delete, remote: true do %>

      <%= image_tag("icon_red_heart.png")%>
```

I don't know how to how to specify the image.

Please teach me.

Comment: I'd guess it's looking for a `icon_red_heart` element with the class `png`. You don't need to click the image, you need to click *the button*.

Comment: Thank you.How do I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe indicated, you are not referencing the button properly. The most resilient way to reference an element is to give it an id and reference it by that id.

Also, the button created by `button_to` may have no content, in which case you'll need to tell Capybara that the button is not visible.

Change the `button_to` line to this:

```
<%= button_to post_like_path(post, like), id: "image-button", remote: true do %>
```

Then change your test to read as follows:

```
scenario "push an image" do
  visit posts_path # Use the name of your path here
  find('#image-button', visible: false).click
end
```

Incidentally, using `method: :delete` in your `button_to` link doesn't do what you would expect. The method is automatically set to `POST`, which is presumably what you want.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me.but An error occurred.  `Unable to find visible css "#image-button"`

Comment: Good. Is the test passing now?

Comment: No,error occurred.`Unable to find visible css "#image-button"`

Comment: Try changing to `find('#image-button', visible: false).click`

Comment: sorry,my error is changed.`LikesController#create is missing a template for this request format and variant.

       request.formats: ["text/html"]
       request.variant: []`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185938/discussion-between-moveson-and-kodai).